# Insert Text array as Headers (VBA, EXCEL)

Tags: excel, vba

**BACKGROUND**

I've created a VBA macro to pull in financial data from various business units.

**OBJECTIVE**

After consolidating each business unit's financial information, **insert a row with column headers** to prepare for a pivot table report.

**APPROACH**

1. Define worksheet
2. Define "header" array
3. Insert 1 row at top of excel sheet, shift all other rows down by 1
4. Insert header array text values into columns

**CODE BASE**

```
Sub addHeaders()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim headers() As Variant

'Define worksheet and desired headers
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONSOLIDATED")
headers() = Array("Fiscal Year", "Month", "Month_Year", "Project", "Local Expense", "Base Expense")


'Insert row for header placement
Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown


'Insert headers
With ws
For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
    .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

**ISSUE(S)**

1. "Object variable or With block variable are not set" @ line `.Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)`

**QUESTION**

- Why is VBA saying that the variable (assuming "ws") was not set when I've clearly defined `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CONSOLIDATED")`

Comment: Are you sure the sheet is in `ThisWorkbook` and not `ActiveWorkbook` ?

Comment: EDIT: For some reason, when I am outside the VBA editor, this code runs appropriately. All code above works. Apologies for an inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that maybe the worksheet isn't where you're telling the code it is, or that the sheet name is in fact incorrect. (Possibly confusing `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook`?)

You could also re-write the code like so:

```
Sub InsertHeaders()

    Sheets("CONSOLIDATED").Cells(1).Resize(1, 6).Value = Array("Fiscal Year", "Month", "Month_Year", "Project", "Local Expense", "Base Expense")

End Sub
```